# Synonym for draught

Tags: synonyms

Looking for a synonym for the word describing flow of air in a room.

I was told that "Draught is what grandparents would call it", so looking for something native and modern (if exists).
One is for the use in writing and one which is maybe less formal?

UPD to clarify my confusion about the word 'draught':

1. my friend told me, after talking to native speaker, that the word sounds little off to the native speaker (as a way to describe the phenomenon). But I couldn't find a friendlier alternative neither by seeking a synonym nor by translating it directly from my language
2. asking my native speaking friends didn't add any clarifications either, options from them were: 'vacuum' and 'breeze'
3. some people here suggested that draught is unwanted event and a result of not well insulated house, but in my language that word (ru сквозняк) can exists as airflow in a new and well insulated house; e.g. the airflow from window through a room door (which often slams because of the wind). Also don't you sometimes want a little of an airflow if there is no AC in a room?

I understand that the selection of my native speakers is maybe too narrowed, since we didn't come up with a better commonly used word, so I decided to take a chance here to get more usable options

Comment: Intentional (air conditioning or opening a window) or unintentional air flow (through cracks and gaps in doors and panels)?

Comment: @KillingTime Both, but we spell it draft in AmE. https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=draft&submit.x=61&submit.y=21

Comment: Would appreciate both examples please. If those are two different words

Comment: @exenza Please answer requests for clarification by [editing your question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/560992/edit) so that it is full and complete in itself without relying on comments. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not aware that there is anything archaic about _draught_ for an unwanted flow of cold air into a room, though with modern heating and insulation there may be less need for the word.

Comment: I'm sure Kate is right about the reason it's becoming old-fashioned sounding. But by extension, one might expect there to be no more recent synonym. // Even with central heating and double glazing, our family still have to use the word 'draught' in the 'unwanted toe-chilling ache-encouraging [nobody minds and therefore nobody mentions  it in summer] through-breeze' sense at times. I know of no decent synonyms.

Comment: For a forced-air HVAC system, *circulation* would be normal for the intentional part. You want to achieve a certain level of circulation to prevent hot and cold spots or stratification. And up to a point, circulation increases comfort. I guess beyond that, it becomes drafty.

Comment: *Draught is what grandparents would call it* simply means that in their day no-one ever thought of ***airflow / ventilation*** as a Good Thing. They struggled to create and keep enough heat inside living spaces, so any noticeable movement of air would probably be an unwanted ***cold** draught*.

Comment: How about "pint pot"?

Answer (score 2):

The general term is   [**airflow** or **air flow**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airflow)

You could talk about "unwanted airflow"

However ...

In the block where I live, all the double-glazing was recently replaced after many years of service.

Subsequent to this, the contractors had to return because residents were experiencing draughts (drafts) where the windows hadn't been perfectly fitted.

No-one, residents or contractors, referred to this as "unwanted airflow" or similar. They were plain and simple draughts.

The word is not archaic. It is very much in common use.

---

Note: As a noun, it is archaic with respect to liquids. *The sailor downed a draught of strong beer.*

However, it is still use as an adjective in the brewing industry, for example, *I enjoy drinking draught beer more than I do bottled beer.*

Comment: @Yosef Baskin - Thanks. I've edited the first line of my answer.

Comment: I disagree that it is archaic for liquids.

Comment: @ GEdgar - I 've modified my final note. Do you still disagree? If so, I'd be interested to see a modern example.

Comment: The OED has no notation that usage is archaic.  In "Harry Potter: Hogwarts Mystery" we can find that "The Draught of Living Death is an extremely powerful Sleeping Draught".

Answer (score 1):

Draught: a current of air (usually coming into
a chimney or room or vehicle).

Synonyms: Draft

Types are;
— Updraft: a strong upward air current.
— Downdraft: a strong downward air current
Type of;
air current , current , current of air , wind
air moving (sometimes with considerable
force) from an area of high pressure to
an area of low pressure.

Comment: You need a source with a link to lock this in as a good answer!

Comment: Your source is incorrect; 'draft' is a spelling variant of the same lexeme, not a synonym. 'Current' doesn't work in most contexts.

Comment: @YosefBaskin It doesn't matter, the air flow to a solid fuel fire in an open grate or stove is called "the draught". Draughts can be created intentionally as well as occurring accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where the idea that "draught" is an obsolete old-fashioned word comes from (at least in British English and because you've spelt it "draught" and not "draft" I'm going to assume that Br English is the context).

The following links are all to websites currently offering advice on draught-proofing thermally inefficient (usually older) homes.

[Energy-Saving Trust](https://energysavingtrust.org.uk/cutting-out-draughts-older-homes/)

[Transition Town Reading (partnered with Reading BC)](https://readinguk.org/draughtbusters/finding-draughts/)

[Ovo Energy](https://www.ovoenergy.com/guides/energy-guides/diy-draught-proofing-homes.html)

These are just the first three of many websites returned by a Google search for "draughty houses" so I don't believe the term is outdated at all.

The homes may be older but the occupants are as likely to be in their twenties as in their seventies and the 'grandparent generation' are more likely to have dealt with the problem over decades or have the knowledge and skills to alleviate it through having grown up in draughty environments

Comment: OP asks for a synonym rather than an explanation that his claim for archaism is wrong (he should have added supporting evidence).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth They're only asking for a synonym (which I'm not sure existsin normal use) _because_ someone has claimed to them that only people of their grandparents' generation and older use "draught". In the absence of a good synonym proof of the currency of "draught" forms an answer in my opinion.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth a post that provides further insight about the issue the OP is asking about, and is too long for a comment, is normally welcomed on SE sites, as it contributes to the purpose of building "a library of detailed answers to every question."

Comment: @Chappo The question has been closed because of lack of research shown; basic dictionary searches would have shown that this sense of draught/draft is not archaic. ELU does not aim to provide 'a library of detailed answers to _off-topic_ questions'.